# Does akka-typed create actors when I use behavior combinator like And?

Tags: akka, akka-typed

In my system I want an actor `A` to send the same messages to actors `B,C,D`. 
Instead of creating the three actors, I was thinking of just combining their behaviors with an [And](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.1/?_ga=1.261906189.1252423665.1450325098#akka.typed.ScalaDSL$$And) behavior contaminator, and then passing that behavior to `A`.

If I do this, how many actors will get created? Will I get just one actor with three behaviors in it, or three actors with separate behaviors?

Here is my real code using the non-And approach, for concreteness (see how `ReplyGenerator` gets passed the references to other actors):

```
object Foobar {
  def foobar(): Behavior[Request] =
  ContextAware[Request] {
    context =>
      val foo1 = context.spawn(Props(Foo1.behavior()), "foo1")
      val foo2 = context.spawn(Props(Foo2.behavior()), "foo2")
      val foo3 = context.spawn(Props(Foo3.behavior()), "foo3")
      val generator = context.spawn(Props(ReplyGenerator.behavior(List(foo1, foo2, foo3))),
        "generator")

      Static {
        case request: Request =>
          generator ! request
      }
  }
}
```

and here is the `ReplyGenerator` behavior that sends the same message to all subscribers:

```
object ReplyGenerator {
def behavior(subscribers: List[ActorRef[Reply]]): Behavior[Request] = {
    Static {
      case request: Request =>
        subscribers.foreach(_ ! Reply.empty)
    }
 }
```

Considering that I want the actors foo 1,2,3 to run in parallel, can `And` combinator be used here instead?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean execution parallelism then you’ll have to create separate Actors (by separate `spawn` calls) as you do in the example code—using `And` will only create a single Actor that runs the contained behaviors one after the other.